# Setting the Python path in Visual Studio Code for file 'launch.json'

Tags: python, configuration, visual-studio-code, pythonpath

I have been using Visual Studio Code for a few years and I find it a really good IDE. I program in Python more than any other language.

It really bothers me that I did not get around to using the IDE's debugger (even though it's a feature).

Error when pressing the debug play button:

```
Failed to launch the Python Process, please validate the path 'export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python'
```

[image]

Checking my PYTHONPATH:

[image]

My *launch.json* file:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "/workspace/h5-automation/",
        "env": {},
        "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput"
        ]
    }
```

Any ideas / suggestions?

Answer (score -7):

If you are on a *nix system, launch the terminal and type `which python` to get the Python path, copy it and paste it as the value of `pythonPath` in the launch.json file.

Comment: ```"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "/workspace/h5-automation/",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        },```