# How to change the path of Python in VS Code?

Tags: python, path

I installed Python 3.10.2 before, but removed it. As I need Python 3.9 for a certain project, I re-installed it. The thing is that I changed the path.

Previous path: D:\Program Files\Python
Current path: D:\Python\Python39

Since I changed it, it doesn't work properly in VS Code. It shows the error below:

```
`Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"D:\Program Files\Python3\python.exe"  "D:\Program Files\Python3\Scripts\pipenv.exe" install': The system cannot find the file specified.`
```

I registered it with the environment variables, of course. How do I fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48009900/setting-the-python-path-in-visual-studio-code-for-file-launch-json ?

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58086334)?  Clearly if you reinstalled Python to `"D:\Python\Python39"` and the interpreter is trying to create a process using `"D:\Program Files\Python3\python.exe"`, it's not going to work...

Comment: None of them did work, so I re-installed it in the original path. But thx for the answers!